# Extra space issue at Keyboard hide show

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iqkeyboardmanager

Hope you are doing well!

I have a used IQKeyboardManager library in a project and I have one screen in which i faced one issue of extra space see in pic.

Issue link (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttlpnuu0ikaf515/Screen%20Shot%202018-02-05%20at%205.47.54%20PM.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to change implementation , but if you used this you won't see any white space

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: self.view.window)
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: self.view.window)
```

//

```
  @objc  func handleKeyboardDidShow (notification: NSNotification)
 {
    let keyboardRectAsObject = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue

    var keyboardRect = CGRect.zero

    keyboardRectAsObject.getValue(&keyboardRect)

    self.containerViewBotcon.constant = -1 * keyboardRect.height 

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,animations: {

       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })

} 

@objc func handleKeyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification)
{

    self.containerViewBotcon.constant = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,animations: {

       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
         self.webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

And UIScrollViewDelegate

```
func scrollViewDidChangeAdjustedContentInset(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   Logger.print("scrollViewDidChangeAdjustedContentInset")
     if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
       for view in webView.subviews {
            if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
               scrollView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Worked